# Consecutive browser tests, not concurrent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I am using `multiCapabilities` to setup multiple browsers. Is there a way to make them consecutive and not concurrent?

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the use case? Why do you need it? Thanks.

Comment: BrowserStack only allows for 2 concurrent browser tests

Answer (score 1):

Since you are allowed to use only 2 testing sessions on browserstack, configure [`maxSessions` setting](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L152):

```
// Maximum number of total browser sessions to run. Tests are queued in
// sequence if number of browser sessions is limited by this parameter.
// Use a number less than 1 to denote unlimited. Default is unlimited.
maxSessions: 2,
```